# I' m trying to add a checkbox in an CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have one small problem, I'm trying to add one checkbox in an checkedlistbox from code, the name changes but it doesen't show it in the checkbox.

```cs
    private void clickToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //create checklist
            CheckedListBox checkedlistbox = new CheckedListBox();
            //spawn checklist at mouse position
            checkedlistbox.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X - 400, MousePosition.Y - 200 );
            //add checkbox
            CheckBox option1 = new CheckBox();

            //checkbox propieties
            checkedlistbox.Width = 500;

            option1.Text = "option1";
            this.Controls.Add(checkedlistbox);
            checkedlistbox.Items.Add(option1);

            //test if name changes
            MessageBox.Show(option1.Text);
        }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPhli.png)

thank you in advance.

Comment: You are creating a new CheckedListBox each time. You should be re-using the CheckedListBox and just adding a new CheckBox to it.

Comment: Also you don't add a CheckBox control to a CheckedListBox control, you add a string (for example "Option 1" and let the CheckedListBox build its checked display for you

Comment: The output you are seeing is due to the CheckedListBox calling the ToString method on the CheckBox control that you pass. However the CheckBox control does not implement an own version for the ToString method, thus the call falls through the inheritance chain until it reaches the Object base class where the ToString method is implemented outputting the name of the class, and this is what you get in the CheckedListBox output.

Comment: Take some tips and tricks: [C# CheckedListBox Use: Windows Forms](https://www.dotnetperls.com/checkedlistbox) and [C# Checked ListBox Control](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-checkedlistbox.htm)...etc.